# Play sound if greater than

Tags: javascript

A little lost here, fairly new to JavaScript.

I am trying to play a sound only if the value of the function `includeHTML()` is equal to or greater than 100.

The value of `includeHTML()` is in a text file that is being read, that works but if I write the value of `includeHTML()` the return in undefined and thus the sound plays.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("mqm-include-html");
    if (file) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Count not found.";}
          elmnt.removeAttribute("mqm-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<body>

<div id ="mqmcount" mqm-include-html="/MQM/mqmcount.txt"></div> 

<script>
includeHTML();

document.getElementById('mqmcount').innerHTML = mqmcount;
var warning = new Audio('warning.mp3');
if (mqmcount >= "100"){
  warning.play();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you put `"100"` in a string ? Also, you never defined `mqmcount`

Comment: Well the txt file contains just a number EG 45, so if greater than 100 in the file play the sound.  I had also tried defining mqmcount but I get undefined returned.

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll("[mqm-include-html]")` instead of iterating over every single tag in the document via `document.getElementsByTagName("*")`.

Comment: What makes you think the browser would query the file automatically ? This would be a major security flaw.

Comment: It's an internal page only so I'm not fussed about security on this occasion.